# EF 5. "Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss" - only changed the column name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = False
```

in my configuration file and the existing model is:

```
Public Property ID() As Integer
Public Property ERP_ArticleCode() As String
Public Property description() As String
```

All I did was change the 3rd column from "description" to "am_description" and ran "update-database -verbose" which resulted in "Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss"!

I do not understand this... why can't I just change a column name and update the database - this shouldn't be a dataloss issue, should it?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how would it know you are changing the column and not deleting it and adding a new one?

Comment: Fair comment. So the only way to fix this is to manually chang the "up" method and make it "alter column" instead of "delete" then "add"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should edit your up and down method and replace the AddColumn and DropColumn instructions with RenameColumn.

EF can't detect if you're renaming a column or if you want to delete one and create a new one.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server Compact, this won't work.  "Direct column renaming is not supported by SQL Server Compact.  To rename a column in SQL Server Compact, you will need to recreate it."

Answer (score 38):

This code below isn't necessary to run your Migration:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = False
```

And, acording to this article ([from entityframework codeplex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1216)), this is an EF error and you can ignore this with `-Force` attribute in your migration.

```
Update-Database -Force
```

or

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration: X -Force
```

It should resolve your problem.

IMO, you should let EF decide what does with your columns, just my opinion.

Comment: You really and truly **ignore** the error with -Force or AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = True.  This is a *very* dangerous thing to put in code that will reach production.  Be *sure* that you want to ignore the issue, as you may lose production data if you are not careful.

Comment: @EricJ. is right about that, you have to be careful with those codes and DO NOT promote to production without knowing what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I just had another minor change that itself was a migration. While trying to update. Check it with `Update-Database -Name "peek"`, just to see if you have too.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen this when I have a migration applied to my database that is in a parallel branch, that my current branch has no knowledge of and I attempt to revert to some older migration.  The best solution there is to switch back to the authoring branch and revert to the latest common migration between the two branches.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this, just type:

> Update-Database -Force

Comment: But all that does is force the data loss! It doesn't address why the entity framework thinks there needs to be data loss, which is clearly explained by kirsten g above. Simply overriding and forcing the database to update and lose the data isn't an ideal scenario for most I'd have though.

Answer (score -8):

You have to change the line

```
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = False
```

to

```
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = True
```

Note: take caution to use true only in your development environment as it can result in data loss after you've deployed for production.

Comment: No. This is just as for mejaiamanuel57's answer above. Forcing the database to drop data is HIDING the problem, not solving it. Kirsten G has explained the situation perfectly, this cannot be dealt with automatically, it requires user intervention in the EF Code and `RenameColumn` should be used instead.